# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Code-first ef core 6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-6.0, code-first

I am building my first application using .Net 6 EF Core.
I want to use the code-first method.
When I try to migrate using Update-Database (after  I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have a "local instance of MySQL80" running on my machine. I can connect to it, using a DB tool, like Dbeaver or the MySQL Workbench.

This is the Connection String I am using:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=my-desired-db-name;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
```

This is my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using react_chores_prototype_api.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I know that this question came up a few times already, but I cant find a solution with the given explantations, also because of lots of different versions over the years. If someone can maybe help me, so i can start working on my project, that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I installed Pomelo MySql Provider and changed the connectionString to a mysql one.
Also i changed my Program.cs like this:

```
var conString = "Server=localhost;Database=my-db-name;Uid=root;Pwd=verySecurePw;";
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString: conString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(conString)));
```

Now it seems to work, I just get following SQL Syntax Error (Not really related to the original Question I guess):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'NOT NULL,
> `Description` nvarchar(200 NOT NULL,
> `Points` int NOT NULL,

Related to this Model:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace react_chores_prototype_api.Models
{
    public class Task
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)"]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(200)"]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int Points { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `c++`? This is in no way C++.

Comment: You cannot use the SQL Server provider with MySQL. Use the Pomelo MySql provider

Comment: You're using a SQL Server connection string and the SQL Server provider. This will never work with MySQL. Use a MySQL connection string instead with the Pomelo MySQL provider